# What is the difference between dissolve and limited dissolve?

Tags: modeling, vertices

On the delete menu with vertices selected, I am presented with two options(among others), dissolve, and limited dissolve. What is the function of each, and when should I use each?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh)

A *dissolve*

> ...effectively turns the selection into a single N-gon. Dissolve works
>   slightly different based on if you have edges, faces or vertices
>   selected. You can add detail where you need it, or quickly remove it
>   where you don't.

While a *limited dissolve*

> ...reduces detail on planer faces and linear edges with an adjustable
>   angle threshold.

From experience, you would use a dissolve to create one large N-gon from several vertices while a limited dissolve can be used to remove excess geometry.

Comment: Note, in 2.67 vertex dissolve has an option `Face Split` which avoids creating ngons from all surrounding faces and isolates the dissolve. So if a vertex has 3 connected edges, the resulting face will only have 3 sides.