# Differences between dissolve and delete?

Tags: operator

Does dissolve works the same way as the delete operator? And what does dissolve and limited dissolve mean?

Comment: Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149/what-is-the-difference-between-dissolve-and-limited-dissolve and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/why-is-limited-dissolve-irregular

Comment: Did you try dissolving/deleting verts and see what happened?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Delete** removes vertices/edges/faces and leaves nothing/a hole in their place.

**Dissolve** combines faces into one big face (ngon) or removes edges only as a separator between faces.

Dissolving an edge between two vertices can be reversed by re-connecting them by pressing <kbd>J</kbd> with both vertices selected.

**Limited dissolve** dissolves (combines into big NGons) all faces that have a certain angle between them (less than 5° by default). Limited dissolve therefore turns large areas filled with many faces into one large face.