# Trying to dissolve edge, but sometimes blender brings the origin to a face instead and doesn't dissolve the face. REALLY annoying!

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to dissolve faces, but half the time it doesn't dissolve them but instead moves the origin to the middle of a face on my object. The same face every time. Why??

[image]

Comment: This is too vague, list the exact steps you performed and perhaps share the object you are working on as well. The image doesn't tell anything. Hard to reproduce this out of thin air when the tool is expected to work as it should.

Comment: make a block and stretch it on the x and y. slice it horizontally about 7 times. (extrude whole side), then try to dissolve edges on side of extrusion

Comment: are you trying to dissolve edges or faces?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C2iZi.png

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about how to use  dissolve..  or about the differences between dissolve and delete:

check this fast video I made for you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vEnOqUZ7Lk

also check:

[Differences between dissolve and delete?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/differences-between-dissolve-and-delete)

and this:

[image: right dissolve operation]